# How do i unzip files from a nested folder?

Tags: bash, zip, terminal.app

Say i have the following `.zip` file:

```
ZipFile.zip
    /zipfolder/
        this.file
        that.file
        theother.file
```

When i try:

`unzip ~/path/to/my/ZipFile.zip -d ~/path/to/my/destination/`

...my desired files are located in `~/path/to/my/destination`**`/zipfolder/`**; however, i'd like `this.file`, `that.file`, and `theother.file` to be unzipped in just **`~/path/to/my/destination/`**.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can with unzip.

You could do one of the following:

1. Zip files inside zipfolder from the start (without the folder itself), and then you could use your unzip the way you wanted:

   > `cd <path>/zipfolder; zip ZipFile.zip *`
2. Make some adjustments after unzipping:

   > `mv ~/path/to/my/destination/zipfolder/* ~/path/to/my/destination/`
   >
   > `rm -f ~/path/to/my/destination/zipfolder`

Comment: `rm -f` still complains _rm: cannot remove 'zipfolder': Is a directory_ for me.  Changing to `rm -rf` would fix that - but this will delete any files or folders inside zipfolder starting with a `.`  Since they won't match the *, they would still be there.  I suggest using `rmdir` instead of `rm -f` - it will delete the directory if empty, and complain otherwise, so you can check what is left